# NewtonSoft Json serializer performance

Tags: c#, json.net

I have an object that I am serializing into Json using NewtonSoft Json.Net. The object is relatively large, the resulting Json is about 300kb, but the serialization process takes around 60 seconds.

The objects to be serialized are just plain POCO's.

The code I am using is

```
string json = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data, Formatting.Indented);
```

Is there anything that can be done to speed up the serialization, adding attributes etc.

EDIT: I have just tested with ServiceStack.Text Json serializer and that takes 48 seconds, still pretty slow.

```
[Serializable]
public class AppointmentItemViewModel 
{
    public AppointmentItemViewModel()
    {
        Data = new AppointmentData();
        Statuses = new List<Status>();
        ClosedDays = new List<ClosedDay>();
        OpenHours = new List<OpenHours>();
    }

    public int CurrentDay { get; set; }

    public int CurrentMonth { get; set; }

    public int CurrentYear { get; set; }

    public int Day { get; set; }

    public int Month { get; set; }

    public int Year { get; set; }

    public int FirstHour { get; set; }

    public int LastHour { get; set; }

    public int CurrentHour { get; set; }

    public int Step { get; set; }

    public bool StaffOnlyBookOwn { get; set; }

    public bool AllowPastAppointments { get; set; }

    public bool AllowBlocks { get; set; }

    public bool AllowGoogleCalendarSync { get; set; }

    public long CurrentUser { get; set; }

    public string DebugInfo { get; set; }

    public bool HasResources { get; set; }

    public string OrganisationId { get; set; }

    public string DefaultTab { get; set; }

    public string StartDay { get; set; }

    public bool AppointmentBreaksOnWeek { get; set; }

    public bool AppointmentBreaksOnMonth { get; set; }

    public AppointmentData Data { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<Status> Statuses { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<LocationStaff> Staff { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<ClosedDay> ClosedDays { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<OpenHours> OpenHours { get; set; }

    public IUserContext UserContext()
    {
        return ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<IUserContext>();
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        // Serialize the Json
        var sb = new StringBuilder();

        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter(sb);

        using (JsonWriter writer = new JsonTextWriter(sw))
        {
            writer.WriteStartObject();

            WriteProperty(writer, "CurrentDay", this.CurrentDay);
            WriteProperty(writer, "CurrentMonth", this.CurrentMonth);
            WriteProperty(writer, "CurrentYear", this.CurrentYear);
            WriteProperty(writer, "Day", this.Day);
            WriteProperty(writer, "Month", this.Month);
            WriteProperty(writer, "Year", this.Year);
            WriteProperty(writer, "FirstHour", this.FirstHour);
            WriteProperty(writer, "LastHour", this.LastHour);
            WriteProperty(writer, "CurrentHour", this.CurrentHour);
            WriteProperty(writer, "Step", this.Step);
            WriteProperty(writer, "StaffOnlyBookOwn", this.StaffOnlyBookOwn);
            WriteProperty(writer, "AllowPastAppointments", this.AllowPastAppointments);
            WriteProperty(writer, "AllowBlocks", this.AllowBlocks);
            WriteProperty(writer, "AllowGoogleCalendarSync", this.AllowGoogleCalendarSync);
            WriteProperty(writer, "CurrentUser", this.CurrentUser);
            WriteProperty(writer, "HasResources", this.HasResources);
            WriteProperty(writer, "OrganisationId", this.OrganisationId);
            WriteProperty(writer, "DefaultTab", this.DefaultTab);
            WriteProperty(writer, "StartDay", this.StartDay);
            WriteProperty(writer, "AppointmentBreaksOnWeek", this.AppointmentBreaksOnWeek);
            WriteProperty(writer, "AppointmentBreaksOnMonth", this.AppointmentBreaksOnMonth);


            writer.WritePropertyName("Statuses");
            writer.WriteStartArray();
            foreach (var item in this.Statuses)
            {
                writer.WriteStartObject();
                WriteProperty(writer, "Id", item.Id);
                WriteProperty(writer, "Description", item.Description);
                WriteProperty(writer, "Color", item.Color);
                writer.WriteEndObject();
            }
            writer.WriteEndArray();


            writer.WritePropertyName("Staff");
            writer.WriteStartArray();
            foreach (var item in this.Staff)
            {
                writer.WriteStartObject();
                WriteProperty(writer, "Id", item.Id);
                WriteProperty(writer, "Name", item.Name);
                writer.WriteEndObject();
            }
            writer.WriteEndArray();


            writer.WritePropertyName("ClosedDays");
            writer.WriteStartArray();
            foreach (var item in this.ClosedDays)
            {
                writer.WriteStartObject();
                WriteProperty(writer, "Year", item.Year);
                WriteProperty(writer, "Month", item.Month);
                WriteProperty(writer, "Day", item.Day);
                writer.WriteEndObject();
            }
            writer.WriteEndArray();


            writer.WritePropertyName("OpenHours");
            writer.WriteStartArray();
            foreach (var item in this.OpenHours)
            {
                writer.WriteStartObject();
                WriteProperty(writer, "DayOfWeek", item.DayOfWeek);
                WriteProperty(writer, "OpenHour", item.OpenHour);
                WriteProperty(writer, "CloseHour", item.CloseHour);
                writer.WriteEndObject();
            }
            writer.WriteEndArray();

            // Main data
            writer.WritePropertyName("Data");
            writer.WriteStartObject();

            writer.WritePropertyName("Appointments");
            writer.WriteStartArray();
            foreach (var item in this.Data.Appointments)
            {
                writer.WriteStartObject();

                WriteProperty(writer, "Id", item.Id);
                WriteProperty(writer, "AppointmentId", item.AppointmentId);
                WriteProperty(writer, "Year", item.Year);
                WriteProperty(writer, "Month", item.Month);
                WriteProperty(writer, "Day", item.Day);
                WriteProperty(writer, "StartHour", item.StartHour);
                WriteProperty(writer, "StartMinute", item.StartMinute);
                WriteProperty(writer, "EndHour", item.EndHour);
                WriteProperty(writer, "EndMinute", item.EndMinute);
                WriteProperty(writer, "ResourceId", item.ResourceId);
                WriteProperty(writer, "Description", item.Description);
                WriteProperty(writer, "Status", item.Status);
                WriteProperty(writer, "IsClass", item.IsClass);
                WriteProperty(writer, "ProcessingLength", item.ProcessingLength);
                WriteProperty(writer, "ClientId", item.ClientId);
                WriteProperty(writer, "ClientName", item.ClientName);
                WriteProperty(writer, "ClientPhone", item.ClientPhone);
                WriteProperty(writer, "ClientNotes", item.ClientNotes);
                WriteProperty(writer, "ClientHasMobile", item.ClientHasMobile);
                WriteProperty(writer, "ClassFull", item.ClassFull);
                WriteProperty(writer, "ClientWaiting", item.ClientWaiting);
                WriteProperty(writer, "PromotionCode", item.PromotionCode);
                WriteProperty(writer, "ArrivalNote", item.ArrivalNote);
                WriteProperty(writer, "Labels", item.Labels);
                WriteProperty(writer, "ReminderSent", item.ReminderSent);
                WriteProperty(writer, "Cancelled", item.Cancelled);


                writer.WritePropertyName("Items");
                writer.WriteStartArray();
                foreach (var appointmentItem in item.Items)
                {
                    writer.WriteStartObject();
                    WriteProperty(writer, "Name", appointmentItem.Name);
                    WriteProperty(writer, "Length", appointmentItem.Length);
                    WriteProperty(writer, "ProcessingTime", appointmentItem.ProcessingTime);
                    WriteProperty(writer, "Resource", appointmentItem.Resource);
                    writer.WriteEndObject();
                }
                writer.WriteEndArray();

                writer.WriteEndObject();
            }
            writer.WriteEndArray();

            writer.WritePropertyName("Resources");
            writer.WriteStartArray();
            foreach (var item in this.Data.Resources)
            {
                writer.WriteStartObject();

                WriteProperty(writer, "Id", item.Id);
                WriteProperty(writer, "Name", item.Name);
                WriteProperty(writer, "BlockLength", item.BlockLength);
                WriteProperty(writer, "StartHour", item.StartHour);
                WriteProperty(writer, "EndHour", item.EndHour);


                writer.WritePropertyName("Breaks");
                writer.WriteStartArray();
                foreach (var breakItem in item.Breaks)
                {
                    writer.WriteStartObject();
                    WriteProperty(writer, "Year", breakItem.Year);
                    WriteProperty(writer, "Month", breakItem.Month);
                    WriteProperty(writer, "Day", breakItem.Day);
                    WriteProperty(writer, "DayOfWeek", breakItem.DayOfWeek);
                    WriteProperty(writer, "StartHour", breakItem.StartHour);
                    WriteProperty(writer, "StartMinute", breakItem.StartMinute);
                    WriteProperty(writer, "Length", breakItem.Length);
                    WriteProperty(writer, "Description", breakItem.Description);
                    WriteProperty(writer, "OtherBreak", breakItem.OtherBreak);
                    WriteProperty(writer, "UserBreak", breakItem.UserBreak);
                    writer.WriteEndObject();
                }
                writer.WriteEndArray();


                writer.WritePropertyName("OpenCloseBreaks");
                writer.WriteStartArray();
                foreach (var breakItem in item.OpenCloseBreaks)
                {
                    writer.WriteStartObject();
                    WriteProperty(writer, "Year", breakItem.Year);
                    WriteProperty(writer, "Month", breakItem.Month);
                    WriteProperty(writer, "Day", breakItem.Day);
                    WriteProperty(writer, "DayOfWeek", breakItem.DayOfWeek);
                    WriteProperty(writer, "StartHour", breakItem.StartHour);
                    WriteProperty(writer, "StartMinute", breakItem.StartMinute);
                    WriteProperty(writer, "Length", breakItem.Length);
                    WriteProperty(writer, "Description", breakItem.Description);
                    WriteProperty(writer, "OtherBreak", breakItem.OtherBreak);
                    WriteProperty(writer, "UserBreak", breakItem.UserBreak);
                    writer.WriteEndObject();
                }
                writer.WriteEndArray();

                writer.WriteEndObject();
            }
            writer.WriteEndArray();

            writer.WriteEndObject();
        }

        return sb.ToString();
    }

    private void WriteProperty(JsonWriter writer, string name, object value)
    {
        writer.WritePropertyName(name);

        if (value == null)
        {
            writer.WriteNull();
        }
        else
        {
            writer.WriteValue(value);
        }
    }

}

[Serializable]
public class AppointmentData
{
    public IEnumerable<ExternalEvent> ExteralEvents { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<Appointment> Appointments { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<Resource> Resources { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
public class ClosedDay
{
    public int Year { get; set; }

    public int Month { get; set; }

    public int Day { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
public class Appointment
{
    public long Id { get; set; }

    public long AppointmentId { get; set; }

    public int Year { get; set; }

    public int Month { get; set; }

    public int Day { get; set; }

    public int StartHour { get; set; }

    public int StartMinute { get; set; }

    public int EndHour { get; set; }

    public int EndMinute { get; set; }

    public long ResourceId { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }

    public long Status { get; set; }

    public bool IsClass { get; set; }

    public int ProcessingLength { get; set; }


    public long ClientId { get; set; }

    public string ClientName { get; set; }

    public string ClientPhone { get; set; }

    public string ClientNotes { get; set; }

    public bool ClientHasMobile { get; set; }

    public bool ClassFull { get; set; }

    public string ClientWaiting { get; set; }

    public string PromotionCode { get; set; }

    public string ArrivalNote { get; set; }

    public string Labels { get; set; }

    public bool ReminderSent { get; set; }

    public bool Cancelled { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<AppointmentItems> Items { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
public class AppointmentItems
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int Length { get; set; }

    public int ProcessingTime { get; set; }

    public string Resource { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
public class OpenHours
{
    public int DayOfWeek { get; set; }

    public int? OpenHour { get; set; }

    public int? CloseHour { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
public class Resource
{
    public Resource()
    {
        Breaks = new List<ResourceBreak>();
        Blocks = new List<ResourceBlock>();
        OpenCloseBreaks = new List<ResourceBreak>();
    }

    public long Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int BlockLength { get; set; }

    public int StartHour { get; set; }

    public int EndHour { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<ResourceBreak> Breaks { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<ResourceBlock> Blocks { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<ResourceBreak> OpenCloseBreaks { get; set; }

}

[Serializable]
public class ExternalEvent
{
    public long Id { get; set; }

    public int Year { get; set; }

    public int Month { get; set; }

    public int Day { get; set; }

    public int DayOfWeek { get; set; }

    public int StartHour { get; set; }

    public int StartMinute { get; set; }

    public int EndHour { get; set; }

    public int EndMinute { get; set; }

    public int Length { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
public class ResourceBreak
{
    public int Year { get; set; }

    public int Month { get; set; }

    public int Day { get; set; }

    public int DayOfWeek { get; set; }

    public int StartHour { get; set; }

    public int StartMinute { get; set; }

    public int Length { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }

    public bool OtherBreak { get; set; }

    public bool UserBreak { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
public class ResourceBlock
{
    public int StartHour { get; set; }

    public int StartMinute { get; set; }

    public int Length { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
public class Status
{
    public long Id { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }

    public int Color { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
public class LocationStaff
{
    public long Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Is the resulting JSON required to be human-readable? If not try removing the `Formatting.Indented` and see if it makes any difference.  This is just a wild shot in the dark, I've never tried it myself. I'd be interested in the results.

Comment: I removed this and it made no noticeable difference.

Comment: Thats what I'm using.

Comment: Documenation suggests that this framework is 50% faster than DataContractJsonSerailzier, 250% faster than JavaScriptSerializer.

Comment: For me it is slower than JavaScriptSerializer.

Comment: Can you share the class you are serializing? How may object are you serializing?

Comment: If you are serializing entity framework pocos, you might be having db performance issues. If your object is a graph, your navigation properties take time, at each level, in each child object, to go back to the db and query data.

Comment: Radu Pascal has a great suggestion.  Whilst my answer will write the json faster, in reality, JSON.NET would never take 60s to write 300kb.    You probably need to find a way to get the data faster.

Comment: I have included the entire class I have created so far and as you can see it is quite complicated. But at the end of the day I am just trying to recurse a class and convert it to a string, so it should be fast.

Comment: Managed to get this down < 1 second. Will post the answer soon.

Comment: @Craig what did the answer end up being, can you post your solution?

Comment: I ended up restructuring the object and manually serialized it and it works much quicker.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Have you tried manually serialising your object into JSON using JSON.NET?  I've found it a lot faster when you have large data and many properties.  Below is an example:

```
public static string Serialise(YourObject data)
{
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter(sb);

using (JsonWriter writer = new JsonTextWriter(sw))
{
    writer.WriteStartObject();

    writer.WritePropertyName("propertyName1");

    if (data.Property1 == null)
    {
        writer.WriteNull();
    }
    else
    {
        writer.WriteValue(data.Property1);
    }

    writer.WritePropertyName("propertyName2");

    writer.WriteStartArray();

    foreach (var something in data.CollectionProperty)
    {
        writer.WriteStartObject();

        writer.WritePropertyName("p1");
        writer.WriteValue(something.prop1);

        writer.WritePropertyName("p2");
        writer.WriteValue(something.prop2);

        writer.WritePropertyName("p3");
        writer.WriteValue(something.prop3);

        writer.WriteEndObject();
    }

    writer.WriteEndArray();

    writer.WriteEndObject();
}

return sb.ToString();
}
```

It means more work, but if performance in your goal, you will not find a faster option.

Comment: This is what I ended up doing. I did need to restructure the object to be less nested lists though.

Comment: For anyone else, I improved JSON serialization of an otherwise simple object orders of magnitude with this approach.

Comment: While this method is orders of magnitude faster than `SerializeObject`, it was still too slow for my purposes. I found a simple `StringBuilder` without all the Newtonsoft.Json overhead was roughly 17x faster.

Answer (score 8):

You should give Jon Bellamy the points for the answer, but here is a little more detail:

I had the same problem with a project I'm working on and I solved it by following the advice on this page:

http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Performance.htm

Specifically, they recommend manually serializing your objects when performance is critical:

```
public static string ToJson(this Person p)
{
    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
    JsonTextWriter writer = new JsonTextWriter(sw);

    // {
    writer.WriteStartObject();

    // "name" : "Jerry"
    writer.WritePropertyName("name");
    writer.WriteValue(p.Name);

    // "likes": ["Comedy", "Superman"]
    writer.WritePropertyName("likes");
    writer.WriteStartArray();
    foreach (string like in p.Likes)
    {
        writer.WriteValue(like);
    }
    writer.WriteEndArray();

    // }
    writer.WriteEndObject();

    return sw.ToString();
}
```

My example in VB looks like this:

```
    Public Function SerializeWords(ByRef oWords As List(Of Word))
        Dim sb As New StringBuilder
        Dim sw As New IO.StringWriter(sb)
        Using oWriter As Newtonsoft.Json.JsonWriter = New Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextWriter(sw)
            With oWriter
                .WriteStartArray()
                For Each oWord As Word In oWords
                    .WriteStartObject()

                    .WritePropertyName("ID")
                    .WriteValue(oWord.ID)

                    .WritePropertyName("Phonics")
                    .WriteValue(oWord.Phonics)

                    .WritePropertyName("Word_")
                    .WriteValue(oWord.Word_)

                    .WritePropertyName("WordLength")
                    .WriteValue(oWord.WordLength)

                    .WriteEndObject()
                Next
                .WriteEndArray()

            End With
        End Using
        Return sb.ToString

    End Function
```

Notice how both functions are strongly typed.  I believe when you use
`Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject()`
it's using reflection to get the job done (which can really add up when you have many objects with many properties).

Anyways... once I wrote my own serializer, my time serializing a list of 250 "Word" objects went from 28 seconds using JsonConvert.SerializeObject() method to 31 milliseconds using my own function.

Answer (score 0):

This still uses the serializer (*which uses reflection internally and*) it ended up solving my speed issue + I didnt have to manually enter everything in. I don't know if the `JsonConvert.SerializeObject()` is different internally than `serializer.Serialize()` but I figured I would share in hopes that this might help

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter(sb);

using(JsonWriter writer = new JsonTextWriter(sw))
 {
  var serializer = new JsonSerializer();
  serializer.Serialize(writer, data);
 }
```

Comment: in this what is the object?

Comment: data

But the object doesnt have to be defined if thats what you're asking (If I remember correctly)

Comment: For reference, this appears to be nearly identical to the internal implementation of `JsonConvert.SerializeObject()`, except the `StringBuilder` is initialized to a capacity of 256, with invariant culture, and the `JsonWriter` has its Formatting field set to the default settings.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same issue, and I found out it was because I had IEnumerable properties. I replaced them with simple arrays and it did the trick.